# Predicting Future Scale Value

Tags: time-series, prediction

I have a data set of the last 2 years worth of values consisting of group adherence rates (10 blood pressures due (denominator) / 6 completed (numerator) for each month - below is example:

[image: Measure Data Table - 2016 - 2017]

What method can I use to predict the monthly vales for 2018?

Any help is greatly appreciated?

Comment: What do the numbers 10 and 6 refer to? Also first writing the denominator and then the numerator would improve readability.

Comment: 10 =  Denom 6 = Num

Comment: The percentage in the image table is the adherence rate - I'm wanting to predict the rate for each month in 2018